# C++ - Segmentation fault at the end of program

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

So I have this program and it runs and does what its suppose to do. But at the end of execution it throws a segmentation fault. I ran the debugger and it says: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault". I ran the debugger line by line and it seems to throw the error in the main function when everything is done.

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 100;

int firstDigit = 0; //vertex number
int verticesCount = 0;
int adjVerticesCount = 0;

class graph
{
    private:
        int n;
        int data[MAX];
        int gptr[MAX][MAX];
    public:
        void create();
        void cleanupMatrix();
        void topological();
};

void graph::create()
{

    cleanupMatrix(); // initialize the adj matrix with zeros

    ifstream infile ("input.txt");
    string line, line_separated;


    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (infile.good())
        {
            while(getline(infile,line)) //reads a line
            {
                if(line.length() == 0)
                {
                    n = verticesCount;
                    topological();
                    verticesCount = 0;
                    continue;
                }

                istringstream iss(line);
                while(getline(iss, line_separated, ' '))    //separate numbers in each line read
                {
                    //convert string digit to int digit
                    int temp; 
                    temp = atoi(line_separated.c_str());

                    if(firstDigit == 0) //On each line the first digit is the vertex. The rest is the adjacency vertices
                    {
                        firstDigit = temp;
                        verticesCount++;
                        data[firstDigit] = firstDigit;
                    }
                    else
                    { //pointing the g array to linked list containing adjacency vertices   

                        adjVerticesCount++;
                        gptr[firstDigit][temp] = 1;
                    }
                }

                adjVerticesCount = 0;
                firstDigit = 0;

            }
                n = verticesCount;
                topological();
                verticesCount = 0;
        }
        infile.close();
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Error: Could not open file 'input.txt'" << endl; //oopsi.. where is the file?
    }
}

void graph::cleanupMatrix()
{
    int x,y;
    for(x=1;x<=MAX;x++)
        for(y=1;y<=MAX;y++)
            gptr[x][y] = 0;
}

void graph::topological()
{

    int flag;
    int i,j;
    int poset[MAX],included[MAX];

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        poset[i]=0;
        included[i]=false;
    }

    int k = 1;
    flag = true;
    int zeroindegree;
    int c = 1;

    while(flag==1)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(!included[i])
            {
                zeroindegree=true;
                for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
                {
                    if(gptr[j][i]>0)
                    {
                        zeroindegree=false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(zeroindegree)
                {
                    included[i]=true;
                    poset[k]=data[i];
                    k=k+1;
                    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
                    {
                        gptr[i][j]=-1;
                        gptr[j][i]=-1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(i==n+1)
        {
            if(zeroindegree==false)
            {
                cout<<"Graph is not acyclic\n";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                poset[k]=data[i-1];
                k=k+1;
               flag=false;
            }
        }
    }

    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("output.txt", ios_base::app);

    cout << "Topological sorting:\n";
    outFile << "Topological sorting:\n";

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout << poset[i];
        outFile << poset[i];

        if(i != n)
        {
            cout << ", ";
            outFile << ", ";
        }
    }

    cout << "\n" << endl;
    outFile << "\n" << endl;
    outFile.close();

    cleanupMatrix();
}

int main()
{
    //Clear the output file
    fstream file;
    file.open("output.txt", fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
    file.close();

     graph obj;
     obj.create();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: short out the problem and post!!!

Comment: @iDebD_gh I dont know where the problem is, so thats why I posted the full code

Comment: Sometimes its good to delete parts, check if the problem persists and repeat.  That way you also reduce the amount of code you paste.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and would be better placed on Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be with

```
int x,y;
for(x=1;x<=MAX;x++)
    for(y=1;y<=MAX;y++)
        gptr[x][y] = 0;
```

Your accessing element outside your array bounds.  Probably should be:

```
int x,y;
for(x=0;x<MAX;x++)
    for(y=0;y<MAX;y++)
        gptr[x][y] = 0;
```

The same goes in your other arrays/loops.  C/C++ start counting a 0, unlike FORTRAN which starts counting a 1 (why, just why...)

Comment: That didnt help, I tried setting them all to 0

Comment: @balbzr Did you also change the comparison from `<=` to `<`?

Comment: You're also reading the "zeroindegree" variable before setting it (line 146 of your program inside the if (i==n+1)).  Try running a tool like "valgrind" on your program; it will help find these kinds of error.

Comment: @ilent2 I just fixed the <= and it seemed to fix the issue..! Thank you so much :)